# WaitForSeconds stops working when app is not in focus or in another tab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, background, coroutine

I've made WebGL game with Unity. Some calculations aren't needed for every frame so I put them in a coroutine. But when game is in background, coroutines work slower than normal and waits extra 5-10 secs.

For example, soldiers run to me and  I fire bullets to them to kill. When they get in range they start to fire too. I checked if enemy is in range with coroutine. When I go other tabs on browser, some enemies gets closer than normal and some comes and passes the game screen. This makes the game unplayable.

Is there a way to make coroutines work properly or I need to put every calculation to update method?

Example code is:

```
private IEnumerator ActionDeciderCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoAction();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Constants.ENEMY_THINKING_TIME);
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice: don't use coroutines for this.

Comment: how do you check the range of the enemy in coroutine? could you give us some code to show that? `Update()` function does almost same thing as coroutine does changing to `Update()` shouldn't be any different

Comment: Did you checked "run in background" on player settings?

Comment: "run in background" setting is checked. If I uncheck it there will be no problem, but i need to play game in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutine is not acting "strangely". The use of `WaitForSeconds` is the problem  which is why I changed the title of this question. The [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) yield instruction is used when you want the wait or the timer to **stop** counting when Unity does not have focus or when in another tab. It will resume when there is a focus or when you return to the tab if using WebGL.

The opposite is [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) which is used when you want the wait or timer to **continue** normally even if the app does not have focus or even when in another tab. It uses unscaled to function. In your case, you need to use the `WaitForSecondsRealtime` yield instruction.

```
private IEnumerator ActionDeciderCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DoAction();
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(Constants.ENEMY_THINKING_TIME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't solve my problem. I guess it's used for waiting certain time when timescale is different than one.

Comment: You are probably doing something else. [This](https://pastebin.com/ei9G1UkW) is my test code. Try it. You will see the timer counting when you go to another tab and return back. Now, replace it with `WaitForSeconds`. It should stop counting when you go to another tab and return back.

Comment: I tested your code on mozilla firefox browser. And result is same. Either it slows down or stops completely after a few seconds. Because i waited 10-20 secs several times but only about 1-2 secs passed.

Comment: I found the solution. Your code was perfectly normal. But the problem was frame rate. Yields refreshes every update, so it slows when in background. I set Application.targetFrameRate = 60; and problem gone away.

Comment: That's weird because I didn't have to do that. Maybe someone messed with your settings. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and resolved it by enabling "Run in Background" in WebGL Player Settings -> Resolution and Presentation.

- ["Run in Background" described in Unity WebGL manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-performance.html#:%7E:text=WebGL%20content%20in%20background%20tabs)
- [Application.runInBackground](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html)