# Unity - How do I make a coroutine continue working after game paused?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hey i have a question about something i'm dealing with for few days now.

I'm making an idle cooking game which pressing button will start a coroutine and at the end of it player gets the reward (short long story of the game).

now i want the cooking process to take a long time for the more advance and worth food .. let's say 1 hour to finish or something like that
so ofc the player won't stay in the game and watch the timer go down,

how can i update the coroutine timer while player pause the game?
i couldn't find anything about that much.

can you even update a coroutine once you start the timer "WaitForSeconds" ?
I do have a script that saves the offline time (time between exit/pause to when game continue)

here's the code of how i implmented the cooking without pausing ..
if i pause the game so the timer freeze until i come back and if i log off so it resets without reward or anything

Please guide me to which way I should approach this issue?

really would love your help, thanks

```
        private FoodData foodData;

        public void CookFood(int foodIndex) // Active cooking by clicking
        {
            foodData = foodManager.GetFoodData(foodIndex);

            if (foodManager.IsFoodOnCooldown(foodIndex))
            {
                return;
            }

            float cookingTime = foodData.CookingTime;
            int profit = foodData.Profit;
            foodManager.SetFoodOnCooldown(foodIndex, true);
            HOGManager.Instance.SaveManager.Save(foodManager.foods);
            InvokeEvent(HOGEventNames.OnCookFood, foodIndex); // starts the loading bar and timer of cooking
            

            StartCoroutine(StartCooking(cookingTime, profit, foodIndex));
        }

        private IEnumerator StartCooking(float cookingTime, int profit, int foodIndex)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(cookingTime);

            playerMoney.UpdateCurrency(profit);
            foodManager.SetFoodOnCooldown(foodIndex, false);

            InvokeEvent(HOGEventNames.MoneyToastOnCook, foodIndex);
        }
```

I tried to implement cooking after offline like so:

```
        public void CookFoodAfterOffline(int foodIndex)
        {
            foodData = foodManager.GetFoodData(foodIndex);

            int offlineTime = Manager.TimerManager.GetLastOfflineTimeSeconds();
            float cookingTime = foodData.CookingTime;
            
            if(foodData.IsOnCooldown == true)
            {
                if (offlineTime >= cookingTime)
                {
                    return;
                }

                timeLeftToCook[foodIndex] = cookingTime - offlineTime;

                int profit = foodData.Profit * foodData.CookFoodTimes;

                foodManager.SetFoodOnCooldown(foodIndex, true);

                InvokeEvent(HOGEventNames.CookFoodAfterOffline, foodIndex); // starts the loading bar and timer of cooking with the time left

                StartCoroutine(StartCooking(timeLeftToCook[foodIndex], profit, foodIndex));
            }
        }
```

but this isn't working well and if a player just pause the game then it won't work as well..

i activate this in the loading of the UIManager
but no success..
Perhaps the problem is with WaitForSeconds...

I just really need a guideline to what way usually is approached dealing with the offline time when a player comes back and timers are update correctly and disribute the rewards after it ended as well
i'm used it's being done with coroutine but perhaps here it's different

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `WaitForSecondsRealtime`, but make sure `Application.runInBackground = true` and set `Application.targetFrameRate = 60`.

Comment: True, true, and I doubt the targetFramerate is needed here. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Xander I remember reading somewhere (not sure if on Unity forums or SO) that this prevented the game from pausing when losing focus when the user "alt-tabbed" to a different app on their mobile or tablet. Not sure if it applies to newer Unity versions, but it's worth a try. My assumption is that it worked because it "forced" the game to run at that framerate and thus internal engine Update() calls still worked and thus everything else was still running. I haven't developed for mobile devices so can't tell you for certain, as I said, it's just something I remembered from some time ago.

Comment: No, Unity doesn't work like that. There is `runInBackground` option in player settings that enables what you're talking about.

Comment: @Xander I know about `Application.runInBackground`, but that doesn't work on mobile. That was the whole point. OK after 1h of wasting time on the Unity forums, in the end it was on SO. No wonder I couldn't remember after 6 years :) Anyway, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699960/waitforseconds-stops-working-when-app-is-not-in-focus-or-in-another-tab . But the workaround was for WebGL. So no guarantees it works on mobile. Still, worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WaitForSecondsRealtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) and it won't prevent your coroutine from working while game is paused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
It didn't seem to work tho..
you might have misunderstood me,
I'm making the game for mobile and it is idle genre so players mostly enter the game , activate the timers and leave for few hours so when they come back it would be complete by then
I understood that waitforsecondsrealtime is for when timescale is 0 but it isn't the case
it's more as OnApplicationPause but i am not sure the right way to do so

Comment: You said about the pause, so my answer was about the paused game. But it seems like you need to track the process between game sessions, and that could be done using a timestamp: at the start of process save it in PlayerPrefs with unique process key, and check later if enough time has passed.